# Unable to run Google's example - Android App Engine Mobile Backend

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am trying to run [this example](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/). I reached upto "Modify the Client Application" and I am then having the following errors (and below is my file organization screenshot:

At this stage, as you can see below, I have the following issues in MainActivity.java.

1. activity_main.xml is called out but the project in its layout folder only has activity_register.xml (see [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-mobile-shopping-assistant-backend-java))
2. "Checkinendpoint" class is undefined but there is a CheckInEndPoint.java in the "MobileAssistant-AppEngine" project, as you can see in the image below. Is that not supposed to get picked up in MainActivity.java - how to import that? (doesnt work like a normal library import, i.e. "MobileAssistant-AppEngine" is not a library that "MobileAssistant" can reference.
3. Same question as above for CheckIn class that is also undefinted in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: its [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-mobile-shopping-assistant-backend-java/tree/master/MobileAssistant-Tutorial/Phase2_Snippets).

Comment: @android-mantra - thank you. I found activity_main.xml in the link, but what about the classes "CheckIn.java" and "CheckInEndpoint.java" - shouldnt these two classes be referenced from "MobileAssistant-AppEngine" - they are being shown as unknown classes in MainActivity.  Thanks a lot for any help here....

Comment: Check out the imports once.

Comment: I just did, took a screenshot - am i missing something silly? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23541335/importerror_mobilestarterkitGAE.PNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete `deviceinfoendpoint-v1-generated-source` & `messageendpoint-v1-generated-source` from the Project-MobileAssistant and then right click on the MobileAssistant-appengine project then click on Generate Cloud EndPoint Library from Google Sub menu.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer did resolve this issue of mine. I guess I need to go back and read up all basics on how the libraries are supposed to be generated(?) because I didnt see this in the tutorial.